# ZNR rating difference between original and replacement PCB

Tags: pcb, three-phase, varistor

I have a defective AC PCB and its potential replacement.

The PCBs are near identical: same voltage zone, same micro controller... except the rating of their 4 ZNR components (surge protection)

The replacement has four ZNR10K471 (410V varistor voltage I believe).
The original has four V 10821U (820V varistor voltage I believe).

Why would there be such a difference?

The 820V (1350V clamping voltage) seems too high to limit spikes on a tri-phase system in Australia where the phase difference voltage is 415V, but that's the way the original is, so this is puzzling to me.

What if I replaced the 410 on the new board by the 820?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varistors help attenuate power line anomalies like lightning-induced surges. They are often present with other circuit protection devices, and the voltage ratings of the different stages are meant to be complimentary in that respect.  However, they have their limits in terms of energy absorption, so if for example you put a 120 V varistor on a 220 V line, it would blow up.

Thus, the first assumption is that the "new" varistors are intended for your electrical grid, as in they are rated above the typical voltages on your mains.  If it doesn't blow up when you turn on power, then you're good there.

Other than that, I recommend leaving them undisturbed for a couple reasons:

- Some engineer intended them for the design, maybe because higher rated varistors/MOVs let too much voltage through that was stressing downstream protection devices.  We can only assume the design engineer knew what they were doing by spec'ing this varistor.
- Varistors and MOVs can silently degrade and go non-functional, and there's no real check or test for it.  Your old board's varistors could be functional, or non-functional, or somewhere on their way to non-functional.  This is why they aren't seen in some product fields - there's no way to know if they are still working.  Thus scavenging old ones is not recommended.

Personally I'd leave them and install the new board.  The new varistors will "kick in" at a much lower threshold than the older ones, thereby reducing stress on downstream components.

Comment: Ok, it could be an improvement of the board design.
But still, reducing the ZNR voltage by 50% seems quite dramatic for a small improvement, so could there be more to it?
Note: I'm in Queensland Australia where storms are frequent and intense, and the power lines are still much aerial, so could this be down to a different standard in surge protection whereby ZNR 410V would trigger too often (410 is clamping at 775V vs 1355V for the 820)
Just trying to figure out why this difference. I would not like to put the new board in and see it burst in flames.

Comment: Note 2: if not obvious: the board in on 3 phases power.

Comment: As I mentioned, the new varistors will "kick in" at a lower threshold, a bit above your mains voltage, as they are supposed to.  Therefore, the new varistors will be "working harder" to give the downstream components an easier time.  It's what varistors are there for - to snuff those high spikes and keep them from the rest of the gizmo.  You just want to be sure that the varistors have a "kick in" voltage at some margin above your mains so that they won't try to snuff mains (blow up in the attempt).  If your mains is 400 V and the varistors go to work at 470 V, then you're golden.

Comment: I've tried... and... as soon as I've put the switch on, !BANG!
The varistors have blown in a blinding flash.
I hope nothing else is damaged downstream, but yeah.
How on Earth can the voltage be so high than 820 are required (as per old board), I just don't get it.
Could it be that this PCB has a higher voltage input from say a transformer?
But then the whole PCB is rated for
380/415V Zone
220/240V
I'm so surprised.

that's probably it. There's a bloody transformer upstream.
So changing the varistors won't cut it as the rest of the board probably won't withstand such high voltage.

Comment: As the board is in the same voltage zone as the old one that means that even tho its input is higher, it must have some specific component to bring the voltage back down. I suspect the higher voltage of the AC unit is so the power components can draw more power with less current. It's quite a big AC unit. Would that make sense to you?

Comment: Hello. Sorry it blew up on you.  Obviously it is not the proper voltage rating, so hopefully the manufacturer can get you a unit that is indeed the one you want.  Or if that is not possible, and if the rest of the board was rated for 415 V mains, then it should be ok and just the varistors are dead.  You could acquire some from an electronics distributor and replace them if you like, using the 820 V versions of course.